# How to call another class from parent program and send data back to the main app

Tags: c#, wpf, class, methods

I am a beginner in c#, but I would like to know  the correct mode of call a method from one .cs file to another and vice versa(if it is possible):

1. I searched the internet how to call some method form **secondApp.cs** to **Mainapp.cs**:
   That is okay to create this line ' secondApp p1 = new secondApp(); ' and then use it like:
   p1.exampleMethod(); This is a way how to call methods form other class (file)...
2. But! Is there a way, *how to send data* into Mainapp.cs like a public string variable? In other words: Once a time I want to call a method from secondApp.cs and there, make a lot of tasks and send or store result/data in Mainapp.cs variable or call the Mainapp method.

---

Mainapp.cs file (just some line to example ONLY!)

```
namespace EXAMPLE
{

public class Mainapp : Window
{

secondApp p1 = new secondApp();
// simple example store some data...
public string[] StoreAllreceivedData;

   public MainWindow()
    {

.
.
.
// call the method from another .cs file.
p1.exampleMethod();

}
}
}
```

---

secondApp.cs file

```
namespace EXAMPLE
{
// The compiler found an error with this line.  | System.StackOverflowException
// If I mark this line as a comment and that part where I try to call the Mainapp method the 
// application works well, without any failure just this desired function does not work.
Mainapp  main = new Mainapp();

public class secondApp
{


public void exampleMethod()
{
.
.
.
// Doing some task and somewhere call a Mainapp method like the following.
// try to send data to MainApp
main.StoreAllreceivedData[1]= "something..."

// And after it continues with the remaining tasks.

.
.
.
}
}
}
```

---

I know it is not working, but I don't know why, or what is the working way to solve my idea.
When I try to start / run the code, this causes some problems: Memory usage goes high and GUI not appeared and also received error; unresponsive WPF application.

Thank you guys for your help in advance.

Comment: There is a very simple answer to your question but I suspect what you're actually trying to do is a bit more complex than you realise? Is there any more context you want to add?

Comment: you can use properties to set values on another class... you could also have a private field and set it using a method parameter

Comment: You need to learn the distinction with cs files, which have classes that can be reused in assemblies, and applications that can use classes in assemblies but cant interactive natively with the same class in other apps. You will need some form of IPC (inter-process communication). I.e named pipes, signalr, wcf, sockets, shared memory... just to name a few

Comment: Are these supposed to be in two different exe?  mainapp and secondapp suggest different applications. Or are they just two classes in the one app?  There are several ways to communicate between two classes. It's considered best practice to decouple using some mechanism like a pub/sub pattern if these are otherwise unrelated in the one app. Another option is to use dependency injection and register one of them with a DI container. Usually you resolve an instance of any and all classes out that container and it provides instances of other classes as parameters to a constructor.

Comment: Your immediate problem is each class creates an instance of the other. This is an infinite loop of each creating the other. Which will only stop when you run out of memory. Don't do that.

Comment: @And, I try to answer for your questions: 1. These classes are in a one app(in one project/solution). There is a one WPF app with GUI and I want to use (make some unique tasks) those classes. 2. And of course, exactly this happened: 'infinite loop; Which will only stop when you run out of memory. ' --> So, these are your mentioned symptoms appeared. Can you suggest a short example how should look the correct solution ? :)  And @ The General, Thanks for your suggestions. I will learn those. Many thanks guy for your all help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a return value in the exampleMethod like this:

secondApp.cs

```
public class secondApp
{
    public string[] exampleMethod()
    {
        string[] data = new string[1];
        data[0] = "something...";
        return data;
    }
}
```

the "string[]" (instead of "void") is the type that will be returned from the method.

In the Main class you can call this method like this.

```
        StoreAllreceivedData = p1.exampleMethod();
```

But, If this really is helping you, you will save a lot of time reading a C# book.